# Why did the use of const in for loop not cause an error

Tags: javascript

```
const todolist= [];
let todolisthtml = '';
     for(let i =0;i<todolist.length;i++){
          const todo = todolist[i];
          const html = <p>`${todo}`</p>;
          todolisthtml += html;
      }
```

Here whenever we iterate through the loop we reassign the variable todo which should cause an error as we used 'const' to declare it, but instead it is running smoothly

Comment: `const` variables are [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#block_scoping)

Comment: that's right, every time loop execute, a new block scoped is created

Comment: Since `const` is block-scoped, it is limited to the curly brackets of for loop and for every iteration of the loop whole block is executed and a new `const todo` is created for that block.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an assignment. It is declaration and initialization.

If you had written

```
const todolist= [];
let todolisthtml = '';
const todo;
for(let i =0;i<todolist.length;i++){
    todo = todolist[i];
    const html = <p>`${todo}`</p>;
    todolisthtml += html;
}
```

that would be reassignment, and would be illegal.

In what you have written, `todo` and `html` go out of scope at the end of the loop block, then a fresh `todo` and `html` are created for the next iteration.

As Jaromanda X says, `const` variables are block scoped. And `let`, too.

Comment: correction: `var` are function scoped, only const and let are block scoped

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X, I'd forgotten that. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `const` in the `for` loop you provided does not cause an error because `const` is used to declare variables that are block-scoped and have a constant value, meaning their value cannot be re-assigned once initialized. In your code, you correctly use `const` to declare the variables `todo` and `html` inside the loop.

The `const` keyword is not causing an error because it is not being used to declare the array `todolist`. The array is declared using `let` which allows re-assignment. In this case, you have initialized the `todolist` array as an empty array `[]`, so there are no elements in it when the loop is executed.

However, it's important to note that since `todolist` is an empty array, the loop will not iterate over any elements, and therefore, the code inside the loop will not be executed. As a result, the `todolisthtml` variable will remain an empty string.

If you want to add elements to the `todolist` array before the loop, you should do so before the loop starts. For example:

```js
const todolist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
let todolisthtml = '';

for (let i = 0; i < todolist.length; i++) {
  const todo = todolist[i];
  const html = `<p>${todo}</p>`;
  todolisthtml += html;
}

console.log(todolisthtml); // Output: <p>item1</p><p>item2</p><p>item3</p>
```